# input types $.each change values one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few input types one below another in dom which i can all select together with their names. Once they have rendered based on the values that are present in them i have to change their classes. I am doing a $.each but it applying the last class to all the other elements as well.

```
$.each($("input[name='./items']"),function(i,val){
    var i =0;
    var date = JSON.parse(val.value);
    var startDate = new Date(date.startdate),
    endDate = new Date(date.enddate),
    today = new Date(new Date().toISOString());
    if((today-startDate>0) && (endDate-today>0)){
        $("input[name='./items']:eq(0)").parent().children('.x-panel').children('.x-panel-header').css('background-image','url(/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default/ext/panel/green-top-bottom.gif)');
    }else if(today-startDate<0){
        $("input[name='./items']:eq(i)").parent().children('.x-panel').children('.x-panel-header').css('background-image','url(/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default/ext/panel/blue-top-bottom.gif)');
    }else if(today-endDate>0){
        $("input[name='./items']:eq(i)").parent().children('.x-panel').children('.x-panel-header').css('background-image','url(/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default/ext/panel/red-top-bottom.gif)');
    }
});
```

Comment: if possible create a JSFiddle to illustrate your problem!

Comment: Why are you overwriting the `i` variable and setting it to `0`?

Comment: This was just a test, i think i is not being picked up.

Comment: It isn't, because you have it in quotes. Javascript doesn't replace variables inside strings, you have to use concatenation with `+`.

Comment: When you're iterating over a jQuery collection you should use `$(selector).each`, not `$.each($(elector)`

Comment: Why are you using `$("input[name='./items']:eq(i)")` anyway? If you want the current element of the loop, use `$(val)` or `$(this)`.

Comment: Yes, all you said helped me. Thanks, Please post an answer and i will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to refer to the current element in the iteration. Also, since there's so much in common in the `if/then/else` blocks, move that out and just set variables for the different pieces.

```
$("input[name='./items']").each(function(i,val){
    var date = JSON.parse(val.value);
    var startDate = new Date(date.startdate),
    endDate = new Date(date.enddate),
    today = new Date(new Date().toISOString());
    if((today-startDate>0) && (endDate-today>0)){
        var el = $("input[name='./items']:eq(0)");
        var color = 'green';
    }else if(today-startDate<0){
        el = $(this);
        color = 'blue';
    }else if(today-endDate>0){
        el = $(this);
        color = 'red';
    }
    if (el) {
        el.siblings('.x-panel').children('.x-panel-header').css('background-image', 'url(/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default/ext/panel/' + color + '-top-bottom.gif)');
    }
});
```